# I am getting an error when using SayHello:function(text)

Tags: angularjs

```
var app=angular.module('myApp',[])

app.factory('testFactory',function()
{
    return {
        SayHello: function(text){
        return "Hello " +text;
    }   
}
});

app.service('testService',function(){
{
    return {
        this.SayHello= function(text){
            return "Hello " +text;  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `factory`, you have an extra `}` closing parenthesis at the end. And in your `service`, you have an extra `{` opening parenthesis at the start.

Comment: syntax error on token "function", if expected

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information and format your code

Comment: var app=angular.module('myApp',[])

app.factory('testFactory',function()
{
 return
 {
  SayHello: function(text){
   
   return "Hello " +text;
  }
  
 }

});

Comment: this is my code for factory method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning an object from you Service. All you need to do is put methods and properties on the `this` pointer. Or alternatively, create a Factory instead in which you can return an object and avoid using `this`. That's the only difference between Services and Factories

```
// As a service
app.service('testService', function() {
    this.SayHello = function(text) {
        return 'Hello ' + text;
    };
});

// As a factory
app.factory('testFactory', function() {
    return {
        SayHello: function(text) {
            return 'Hello ' + text;
        }
    };
});
```

You'll notice that in the Service we don't have to return anything. That's because Services are instantiated using `new`. Factories on the other hand are instantiated as a regular function call so we have to return what we want them to have. In this case, our own homemade object with SayHello as a method.

Comment: But while using the factory method , i am getting an error for this that syntax error on token "function" , if expected.

Comment: Can you also post the code that uses the Factory? Sounds like a typo or something simple like a missing or extra curly brace.

Comment: var app=angular.module('myApp',[])

app.factory('testFactory',function()
{
 return
 {
  SayHello: function(text){
   
   return "Hello " +text;
  }
  
 };

});

Comment: The error must be coming from another part of the code. That factory looks fine.